# How to use regex to limit 0 - 100 and NOT blank input in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a problem about regex expression in Angular/Javascirpt.

I have a regex expression as below. This is work for limit 0-100.

But how to limit the input is not blank ? For example user type something text in the input textfield, then user press the delete or backspace key to empty the textfield, the regex work !

```
ng-pattern="/^[0-9][0-9]?$|^100$/"
```

I already put the regex in [this](https://regex101.com/r/vBL2bp/1).

Comment: Try `ng-pattern="/^(?:[0-9][0-9]?|100)?$/"`

Comment: Thanks you help, but i want to NOT allow when textfield is empty

Comment: So, your regex already does not allow it to be empty. Else, provide a fiddle showing the issue.

Comment: um. because my textfield have default value when generate in the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following pattern:

```
^(?:[1-9]?\d|100)$
```

It will allow `100` and other number below, but not numbers starting with `0`such as `01`. Blank is also not matched but `0` alone is.

[See the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sdd62z/1)

Comment: it works, but why empty my textfield content when textfield have default value ?

Comment: @tommychoo You mean that when you fill a regex in `ng-pattern`, it empties the default value you had previously defined?

Comment: Yes, when i use your regex pattern, that will clear the default value textfield.

Comment: @tommychoo What is your default value?

Comment: @tommychoo It's maybe a problem you have with angular usage. The pattern in my answer matches `87` and shouldn't fail the check. How do you initialize it? Do you use a `ng-model`?

Comment: Yes, my default value of textfield is use ng-model to init. but i use your regex , then the default value can't show when generate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134670/discussion-between-niitaku-and-tommychoo).